# Calc III Stoke's Theorem Calculate $\int_C v \cdot dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

The sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ intersects the plane $x + 2y + z = 0$ in a curve $C$. Calculate $\int_C \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{r}$, where $\vec{v} = 2yi -zj +2xk$

So I solved this question by taking the curl of $\vec{v}$ and dot-producting that with the normal vector getting an answer of $\pm 5a^2\pi$ but in the solution they keep it in terms of $dS$ and get $\pm \frac{5}{\sqrt 6}a^2\pi$ I don't understand where the $ \sqrt 6$ comes from if anyone could shed some light on that thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made a simple mistake in using **unit** normals! As it seems you have just used the vector $(1,2,1)$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,2,1)$ for the unit normal of the plane $x + 2y + z = 0$. :)

Comment: In my notes there are two ways to solve Vector surface integrals, one by just using the dot product on the normal vector and the other by using the dot product on the unit normal multiplied by the magnitude of the normal vector. I used the first method so i don't understand why i would need the unit normal.

Comment: @katierusso: If you want us to debug your solution, you should write it down in the question. :)

Comment: @katierusso: I do suggest to take look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561291/must-vecn-be-a-unit-normal-vector-stokes-theorem/1561298#1561298).

Comment: could you please debug it? :)

Comment: @katierusso: You should write what you have tried. I can not debug out of nothing! :)